# There is no Driver for DataStax Graph in PHP

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-php-driver, datastax-enterprise-graph

DataStax Enterprise 5.0 doesn't have a PHP driver. I need to use DSE Graph, What do I do ? Write Python Code and somehow run it using PHP ?
Is there a timeline of when they are going to release this ? Any ideas anyone ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the PHP driver is built on top of the DataStax Enterprise C++ driver, it necessarily lags releases on that driver. There are no firm dates, but I can say the DSE C++ driver should be GA mid-October 2016, and the PHP driver will be RC status some weeks after that.

The alternative for now is to write in any of the other [languages with GA graph support](http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/current.html): Java, Python, Ruby, node.js, or C#.

Comment: Just wanted a timeline! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wait, but in the link you give me. It suggests that C++ drivers are already available. There is already a  C++ Driver for DSE right ?

Comment: It shows docs for the C++ 1.0 API, which is only in RC status presently. That's not obvious in the docs, but you would find that searching for the released package.

Comment: Nothing yet. Can you give a rough timeline.

Answer (score -1):

Had contact with datastax and get it running now on CentOS 7:

```
# Download and install the dependencies for PHP DSE driver v1.0.0
sudo rpm -Uvh http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/centos/7/dependencies/libuv/v1.11.0/libuv-1.11.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh http://downloads.datastax.com/cpp-driver/centos/7/dse/v1.1.0/dse-cpp-driver-1.1.0-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
sudo rpm -Uvh http://downloads.datastax.com/php-driver/centos/7/dse/v1.0.0/php70w-dse-driver-1.0.0stable-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
# Ensure that the PHP DSE driver is installed correctly
php -i | grep -A 11 "^dse$
```

We are running here with zend server and we are getting the following error when trying to install the dse driver rpm:

```
error: Failed dependencies:
php(api) = 20151012-64 is needed by php70w-dse-driver-1:1.0.0stable-1.el7.centos.x86_64
php(zend-abi) = 20151012-64 is needed by php70w-dse-driver-1:1.0.0stable-1.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Checking we had the right version with:

```
phpize -v
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20151012
Zend Module Api No:      20151012
Zend Extension Api No:   320151012
```

We solved this with installing the rpm with the flag nodeps:

```
sudo rpm -Uvh --nodeps http://downloads.datastax.com/php-driver/centos/7/dse/v1.0.0/php70w-dse-driver-1.0.0stable-1.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
```

Then copy the dse.so to the plugin directory for PHP. And load the extension with a .ini file or directly in php.ini.

```
sudo cp /usr/lib64/php/modules/dse.so /usr/local/zend/lib/php_extensions/
```

The documentation of the PHP DSE API you can find here:

[PHP DSE API](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/php-driver-dse/1.0/features/)